# How to show "You're offline" when web view app open without internet in Flutter Web view App?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making a webview application in flutter,
here is the code of webview

```
 WebView(
            initialUrl: 'https://deoxy.tech/',
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
              _controllerCompleter.future.then((value) => _controller = value);
              _controllerCompleter.complete(webViewController);
            },
          ),
```

and the web view is working fine, but the problem is when there is no internet connection, then the application shows a loading error like this

[image]

I want to show another widget or image instead of this loading error.
like when there is no internet connection I need to show "No Internet connection" screen/widget like this.

[image]

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [this Package](https://pub.dev/packages/data_connection_checker) For checking Internet connection is available or not.

```
bool result = await DataConnectionChecker().hasConnection;

 return Scaffold(
      body: WebView(
        if (result == true) {
        initialUrl: "https://google.com/",
        onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController){
          _controller.complete(webViewController);
        },}
        else{
          //i am not connected to any network
        }
      ) );
```

Answer (score -1):

checking the internet in flutter is only available when you are on android or ios ,
it's like this because when you open your web application and  it comes up it means you have a connection and if it doesn't you don't have a connection so c checking internet is meaningless